# Can not get the id from the cart session

Tags: php

I'm working on my homework. I have a cart session and I can get on the attribute in mySql database base on the product id.

```
<?php
$total_price=0;
if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : null)
{
echo "<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>";
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $product) {
    $the_query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=" . $product->id;
    $the_product = $db->query($the_query) or die('Query failed: '.mysql_error());
        $the_product->execute();
        $the_product->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        while ($row = $the_product->fetch()){
        $total_price = $total_price + $row->price*$product->quantity;
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo "<img src='".$row->image_url_small."' /></a></td>";
        echo "<td><strong>".$row->name."</strong></td><td><em>$".$row->price."</em>";
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td><input type="text" id="'.$row->id.'" class="override" value="'.$product->quantity.'"/></td>';
        echo '<td><a href="do_deletecart.php?id="'.$row->id.'">Delete item </a></td></tr>';
    }}

    echo "<tr><td colspan='2'></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td style='text-align:center;font-size:40px;'>$</td><td><strong>Total</strong><br /><em>$".$total_price."</em></td></tr>";

}
 else {
echo "Your cart is empty.";
}
?>
```

Update
I can pass the id to do_deletecart.php. But now I can delete the product from cart
do_deletecart.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$product = $_GET['id'];

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$value) {

if($product == $value)
 {
     unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
         break;

 } }

header("location:cart.php");    

?>
```

Comment: Did you start your session at the top of your file?

Comment: yes, I did. And I can get all other values except the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming that `$row->id` contains what you expect, you have enclosed it with quote marks, which will essentially terminate the `<a>` element's `href` attribute.

You need to update your code as follows:

```
echo '<td><a href="do_deletecart.php?id='.$row->id.'">Delete item </a></td></tr>';
```

Also, you might want to check that you have actually started the session. In order to access the `$_SESSION` superglobal, you need to first have called `session_start()` before any output was sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you include
`session_start();` before using $_SESSION